# I cannot delete or update multiple record using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I want to delete multiple record using entity framework but i cannot delete.

i am trying following code

```
db.FileTypeWithProducts.Where(x => x.ProductID == proid).ToList().ForEach(db.FileTypeWithProducts.DeleteObject);
```

In above statement vs 2013 gives error

```
Error   1   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FileTypeWithProduct>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject' and no extension method 'DeleteObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FileTypeWithProduct>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: you cant delete multiple records in EF, for that you have to create a custom method that will accept list of objects and delete them one by one.

Comment: @Amit look below is solution for deleting multiple record given by Tallmaris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either `Remove` or `RemoveRange` (at least with EF6):

```
db.FileTypeWithProducts
    .Where(x => x.ProductID == proid).ToList()
    .ForEach(ft => db.FileTypeWithProducts.Remove(ft)); 
    // you need a lambda since the expected method needs to return void.
```

or:

```
db.FileTypeWithProducts
    .RemoveRange(db.FileTypeWithProducts.Where(x => x.ProductID == proid).ToList());
```

Comment: You're welcome... Can you please confirm if both solutions work? I'll update the answer :)